# Performing SVD in spark ( Sparse Matrix vs Dense Matrix) using RowMatrix

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib

I have a conceptual question. We can read sparse matrices in Spark and convert them into  Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) format using the `Matrices.sparse` method from the `import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrix, Matrices}` class. If I convert this into `RowMatrix` Format and perform SVD, will it be faster and more efficient than directly converting the dense matrix into the `RowMatrix` format and performing SVD?

Common sense may suggest that sparse matrix would be faster but is it indeed faster?, does the `RowMatrix` interpretation of the sparse matrix give it a performance boost? If so why?

Comment: Doesn't SVD require RowMatrix as an input? How can we directly compute?

Comment: My requirement needs to use Spark, so, unfortunately, I can't use scala based libraries. Spark only. So back to my initial question is it faster or slower using sparse?